# Laravel: Error "Creating default object from empty value" when update/edit form

Tags: laravel

I got this error when I tried to update data users. I have browse to other source but don't found answer from my problem.

> ErrorException
> **Creating default object from empty value**
> http://localhost:8000/ec-admin/users/updateact/%7B$users-%3Eid%7D

This is my user controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\User;
use File;

public function updateact($id, Request $request)
{
    // Menyiapkan data gambar yg diupload ke variable $file
    $file_name = $request->hidden_image;
    $file = $request->file('file');
    if($file != '')
    {
        // Validasi data
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name'          => 'required|alpha',
            'email'         => 'required|email',
            'level'         => 'required|alpha',
            'password'      => 'required',
            'file'          => 'required|file|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:1048'
        ]);

        $file_name = time()."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();

        // Isi dengan nama folder tempat kemana file diupload
        $upload_directory = 'p_users';
        $file->move($upload_directory, $file_name);

        // Hapus file
        $gambar = User::where('id',$id)->first();
        File::delete(public_path('p_users/'.$gambar->file));

     }
    else
    {
        // Validasi data
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name'          => 'required|alpha',
            'email'         => 'required|email',
            'level'         => 'required|alpha',
            'password'      => 'required'
        ]);

    }

    // Update data
    $users = User::find($id);
    $users->name        = $request->name;
    $users->email       = $request->email;
    $users->level       = $request->level;
    $users->password    = $request->password;
    $users->file        = $file_name;
    $users->save();

    return redirect('/ec-admin/users')->with('usrsupdateno', 'Data update Successfully!');
}
```

And this is my user form view. Please help because I new in laravel.

```
<form role="form" action="/ec-admin/users/updateact/{$users->id}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    @method('put')
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$users->id}}"><br/>
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="#">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="#" value="{{$users->name}}" autofocus>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="#">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="#" value="{{$users->email}}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="#">Level</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="level">
                        <option disabled selected>-Choose-</option>
                        <option value="user" {{($users->level === 'user') ? 'Selected' : ''}}>User</option>
                        <option value="admin" {{($users->level === 'admin') ? 'Selected' : ''}}>Admin</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="#">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="#" value="{{$users->password}}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Profile Pic</label>
                    <div>
                        <img src="{{ url('p_users/'.$users->file) }}" width="100">
                    </div>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="file">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_image" value="{{$users->file}}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
    <div class="box-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my route, I hope this help.

```
Route::get('/ec-admin/users/update/{id}', 'UsersController@update')->name('usrupdate');
Route::put('/ec-admin/users/updateact/{id}', 'UsersController@updateact');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your form action change {$users->id} to {{$users->id}}
it would work

but for best practice you should assign a name to your route then use the route helper

Comment: What do you mean route helper? Can you explained? Thanks

Comment: in your routes/web.php instead of 

`
Route::put('/ec-admin/users/updateact/{id}', 'UsersController@updateact');

`
make it 

 `
Route::put('/ec-admin/users/updateact/{id}', 'UsersController@updateact')->name("actupdate");
`

then in the form action call
`
{{route("actupdate", ["id"=>$users->id])}}
`

Answer (score 2):

This error is triggered when `yourObj` is `NULL` or not yet initialized:
That's because your `$users = User::find($id);` return **NULL** ,

Your form URL is incorrect and so Eloquent can't find your expected User.

#### Best practice

Change your **PUT** route to :

```
Route::put('/ec-admin/users/updateact/{id}', 'UsersController@updateact')->name('act.update');
```

Then in your `<form>` change `action="/ec-admin/users/updateact/{$users->id}"` to

```
action="{{ route('act.update',$users->id) }}"
```

#### Simple solution

Change your **form** action from `action="/ec-admin/users/updateact/{$users->id}"` to

```
action="/ec-admin/users/updateact/{{ $users->id }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your explained, and your answer works too!